# Insert date into SQL Server database via TableAdapter vb.net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, vb.net, tableadapter

I'm trying to insert a row into my db through a `TableAdapter`.

The table is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Grinding]
(
    [RMID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BatchID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Batch] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmount] [numeric](18, 8) NOT NULL,
    [Expired] [date] NULL,
    [Portions] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartingTime] [date] NULL,
    [EndTime] [date] NULL,
    [IsFinished] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Canceled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Remarks] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Experiment] [bit] NOT NULL,
)
```

The query on the `TableAdapter` is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Grinding (RMID, Batch, TotalAmount, Portions, IsFinished, Canceled, Remarks, Experiment, Expired)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

I take the date value from textBox and I insert the date in the this format : `05/10/2016` as `MM/dd/yyyy` .

Then in my code I do this :

```
Dim dt As DateTime = txtValidity.Text
Dim dateString As String = dt.ToString("MMddyyyy") 'CONVERT TO SQL DATE FORMAT
```

and then I insert with the TableAdapter :

```
da.InsertQuery(Materials, Batch, Amount, Portions, False, False, 
               Remarks, Experiment, dateString)
```

For some reason I always get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I tried to convert my date to several string formats but nothing works.

Thanks for any helpful information.

Comment: Doesn't the `TableAdapter` give you a method with a `DateTime` parameter?? You should try to avoid parsing dates back and forth from and to strings all the time - it just calls for trouble ....

Comment: the tableadapter gives me a method with string parameter for the dates...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim dateString As String = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Also follow the following link for more help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0):

Change your Table Column to store a date object, instead of a date string. Let .net and sql deal with making that conversion. There's no reason for you to.

However, the sql date string format can be different. For my setup, it's 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:000'

Comment: the tableadapter still gives me a method with string parameter in the date objects, even when i tried to generate my own method it still asks for a string. i changed the col definition to System.DateTime and still all generated functions asks for string

Answer (score 0):

As presented, Expired is a date while you are trying to pass a string.  Go to your tableadapter properties page and expand "InsertCommand"  The last line is "Parameters".  Click on the "..." after "(Collection) to open the "Parameters Collection Editor"  Click on all of your parameters that are of type Date and change the "DBType" to DateTime2.  Click on OK.  Now you can just pass a date parameter without having to mess around with strings.

As long as txtValidity.Text is a valid date, the Expired parameter is CType(txtValidity.Text, Date)

By the way, I assumed you are using SQL Server.  If you are using Access, the type of your date parameters should be just Date ... I think.  It's been a looooong time since I worked in Access. Just change to parameter to whatever the Access date type is called.

Comment: You should mark someone's answer as the answer to your question so that people like me won't work up a reply THEN notice your question is 4 months old but not yet answered.